# Looping array inside and array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm want to loop an array inside and array using JavaScript

```
outerArray = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];
innerArray = ["val-1","val-2","val-3"];
```

so that the console logs out:

```
1,val-1
2,val-2
3,val-3
4,val-1
5,val-2
6,val-3
7,val-1
8,val-2
9,val-3
10,val-1
```

Using:

```
for (var i = 0; i < outerArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Obviously logs:
1,2,3,4,5,.....

However I cant use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < outerArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(i+','+innerArray[i]);
}
```

As this would give **undefined** after "val-3" as its a different length to the outer array.

Comment: That's not an outer array, that's simply starting the loop over. Loop up the modulus operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want

```
console.log(outerArray[i]+','+innerArray[i%innerArray.length]);
```

[Reference on the % operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Comment: @zaf that's why I added a link to the operator's description.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pzsyg/ - also, I think you meant `console.log(outerArray[i]+','+...` as the question is asked

Comment: @ToreHanssen Probably, yes.

Comment: @dystroy ah yes, that link on the mozilla developer network explains it all.

Answer (score 0):

```
outerArray.forEach(function (elem, idx) {
    console.log(elem + ", " + innerArray[idx % innerArray.length]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bh4bs/

Comment: Let's precise that forEach isn't compatible with IE8 : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach